# Access original JSON (un-restangularized) from getList

Tags: angularjs, restangular

Interestingly enough (at least to a newbie) that IF you return the entire list from DJANGO (and possibly other back ends), the response back may change. In my case the DJANGO Rest Framework returned an array once I returned the pagination off requiring me to rewrite this function.

---

This seems to do it:

```
RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response) {
  var newResponse = response;
  if (angular.isArray(response)) {
    angular.forEach(newResponse, function(value, key) {
      newResponse[key].originalElement = angular.copy(value);
    });
  } else {
    newResponse.originalElement = angular.copy(response);
  }

  return newResponse;
});
```

from:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-access-the-unrestangularized-element-as-well-as-the-restangularized-one

---

I would like to be able to strip out the additional methods added from restangular so that I can compare a simple JSON object to a restangularized version using angular.equals or similar method.

The workflow is

```
> 1: get array of objects from server 
> 2: allow the user to add a new item to the list (via form) 
> 3: only enable the save button IF this exact object is not already in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer and update in the original post.